# JSF redirect to another bean from bean method

Tags: jsf

I have a scenario where I have to invoke another bean and registered bean attributes before rendering the JSF page as JSF page have reference to bean attributes for rendering response.

I am looking for best option to implement such scenario. I tried to represent required scenario in form of pseudo-code for better understanding.

Page A --> have button "View Detail" bind with BeanOne.getDetail() -- Scope is session.

**BeanOne.getDetail()**

process the request
 - call the backend method to get detail
 - if (type == XYZ) then invoke BeanTwo.getTypeXYZ() and redirect as per navigation rule defined for BeanTwo.getTypeXYZ()
 - else if (type == RST) then invoke BeanThree.getTypeRST() and redirect as per navigation rule defined for BeanThree.getTypeRST()

**BeanTwo.getTypeXYZ()**

- process the request
- call the backend method to get detail
- set this.attributeB = value returned from backend method.
- navigate to Page B

**BeanTwo.getTypeRST()**

- process the request
- call the backend method to get detail
- set this.attributeC = value returned from backend method.
- navigate to Page C

Something like having bean method name in navigation rule

`<navigation-rule>`
    `<from-view-id>Page A</from-view-id>`
    `<navigation-case>`
        `<from-action>#{beanOne.getDetail}</from-action>`
        `<from-outcome>xyz</from-outcome>`
        `<to-view-id>#{beanTwo.getTypeXYZ}</to-view-id>`
    `</navigation-case>`
    `<navigation-case>`
        `<from-action>#{beanOne.getDetail}</from-action>`
        `<from-outcome>rst</from-outcome>`
        `<to-view-id>#{beanTwo.getTypeRST}</to-view-id>`
    `</navigation-case>`
`</navigation-rule>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `navication-rule` in `faces-config.xml`

```
<navigation-rule>
 <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>XYZ</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>pageB.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
 <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>RST</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>pageC.xhtml</to-view-id>
  <redirect/>
 </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

in bean

```
getTypeXYZ() {
   ...
   NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
   nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, "XYZ");
}
```